# Pop up window not appending text

Tags: asp-classic, popupwindow, window.open

I am trying to implement a 'Trace Window' pop up window when I enter a website, and then send messages to that window throughout the website in Order to diagnose some of the more awkward issues i have with the site.
The Problem is that the page changes, if The trace window already exists, all content is removed, before the new TraceText is added. 
What I want is a Window that can be sent messages from any page inside the website.

I have a javascript Script debugger.js which I include as a script in every screen (shown below) I would then call the sendToTraceWindow() function to send a message to it thoughout the website. this is currently Mostly done in vbscript at present, due to the issues i am currenctly investigating.
I think it is because i am scripting in the debugger.js into every screen, which sets the traceWindow variable = null (see code below) but I do not know how to get around this!

Any help much appreciated.
Andrew

code examples:

**debugger.js**:

```
var traceWindow = null

function opentraceWindow()
{
   traceWindow = window.open('traceWindow.asp','traceWindow','width=400,height=800')
}

function sendToTracewindow(sCaller, pMessage)
{

   try
   {
      if (!traceWindow)
      {
         opentraceWindow()
      }

      if (!traceWindow.closed)
      {
         var currentTrace = traceWindow.document.getElementById('trace').value
         var newTrace = sCaller + ":" + pMessage + "\n" + currentTrace
         traceWindow.document.getElementById('trace').value = newTrace
      }
   }
   catch(e)
   {
         var currentTrace = traceWindow.document.getElementById('trace').value
         var newTrace = "error tracing:" + e.message + "\n" + currentTrace
         traceWindow.document.getElementById('trace').value = newTrace
   }

}
```

**traceWindow.asp** - just a textarea with id='trace':

```
<HTML>
   <head>
      <title>Debug Window</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <textarea id="trace" rows="50" cols="50"></textarea>
   </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: what are you trying to trace again?  To diagnose what type of errors?

Comment: Not Necesarily errors, but any Trace that I may find useful :). For Example, I may want to show in the TraceWindow what the String value sStatus is a given moment in time, so may call sendToTraceWindow("window_onmousemove",iStatus) or maybe when someone presses the 'Save' button, I would log That to the traceWindow sendToTraceWindow("save_mouseup","Save button pressed").  So not errors -  just text that I may find useful in finding bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way around the fact that your traceWindow variable will be reset on every page load, therefore rendering your handle to the existing window invalid.  However, if you don't mind leveraging LocalStorage and some jQuery, I believe you can achieve the functionality you are looking for.

Change your trace window to this:

```
<html> 
   <head> 
      <title>Debug Window</title> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="YOUR_PATH_TO/jQuery.js" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="YOUR_PATH_TO/jStorage.js" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="YOUR_PATH_TO/jquery.json-2.2.js" />
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var traceOutput;
        var traceLines = [];
        var localStorageKey = "traceStorage";

        $(function() {
          // document.ready.
          // Assign the trace textarea to the global handle.
          traceOutput = $("#trace");
          // load any cached trace lines from local storage
          if($.jStorage.get(localStorageKey, null) != null) {
            // fill the lines array
            traceLines = $.jStorage.get(localStorageKey);
            // populate the textarea
            traceOutput.val(traceLines.join("\n"));
          }
        });

        function AddToTrace(data) {
          // append the new trace data to the textarea with a line break.
          traceOutput.val(traceOutput.val() + "\n" + data);
          // add the data to the lines array
          traceLines[tracelines.length] = data;
          // save to local storage
          $.jStorage.set(localStorageKey, traceLines);
        }

        function ClearTrace() {
          // empty the textarea
          traceOutput.val("");
          // clear local storage
          $.jStorage.deleteKey(localStorageKey);
        }
      </script>
   </head> 
   <body> 
      <textarea id="trace" rows="50" cols="50"></textarea> 
   </body> 
</html>
```

Then, in your pages where you want to trace data, you could modify your javascript like so:

```
var traceWindow = null;                 
function opentraceWindow() {                      
  traceWindow = window.open('traceWindow.asp','traceWindow','width=400,height=800');
}

function sendToTracewindow(sCaller, pMessage) {
  traceWindow.AddToTrace(sCaller + ":" + pMessage);
}
```

Every time a new page is loaded and the trace window is refreshed, the existing trace data is loaded from local storage and displayed in your textarea.  This should achieve the functionality that you are looking for.

Please be kind on any errors - I'm winging this on a Monday morning!

Finding the jQuery library should be trivial.  You can find the jStorage library here: http://www.jstorage.info/, and you can find jquery-json here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Comment: Excellent Thank you brad. It's only ever going to be 'switched on' in a development environment, so I have no problem with the Local storage. Seems like a good solution. I have not used jquery before, so I shall give it a go!